# calculate the area of circle ,ellipse (dynamic method)

Tags: c++, qt

I draw a circle in real time and I want to calculate the area of this( circle ellipse )by calculating the pixel number  each time the shape is changed by the cursor
.

label.h

```
QPainter painter;
       QLine mLine;
       QRect mRect;
       QRect mCirc;

label.cpp
void  Label::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event){
    QLabel::paintEvent(event);

 QPainter painter(this);
 QPen pen(Qt::red, 3, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::RoundCap, Qt::RoundJoin);

 painter.setPen(pen);
    if(mousePressed){

        switch (_paintMode) {
        case PaintRect:{
            painter.drawRect(mRect);
            float s=mRect.width()*mRect.height();


        }break;
        case PaintLine:
        {
            painter.drawLine(mLine);
            float d=sqrt(pow(mLine.p1().x()-mLine.p2().x(),2)+pow(mLine.p1().y()-mLine.p2().y(),2));



        }break;
        case PaintCirc:{
            painter.drawEllipse(mCirc);

        }
}
}
}
```

Comment: What's your problem/question?

Comment: I do not know how I can calculate the area of ​​a (circle, ellipse) by the number of pixels if you have an idea that can help me.

Comment: I believe you must use math formulas instead of counting the pixels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`QPainter::drawEllipse` will draw an ellipse that fits the given `QRect`.

The size of a `QRect` are specified in pixel. So, you can use the classic formula to calculate the area of an ellipse:

```
long areaInPixel = M_PI * rect.width()/2 * rect.height()/2
```

Comment: if i want to draw a free form and calculate its surface how can i do it?

Comment: The general way is to fill the area with shapes (such as triangles) and calculate the sum of their areas. But, you have a some workaround in Qt to calculate the area of irregular shapes. It will depend on how you will create it.